# How to listen for mouse movements correctrly in JME3?

Tags: java, 3d, jmonkeyengine

I wish geometry to rotate around it's center by mouse movement.

Similar like camera rotates in sample application.

The program below should rotate the cube on mouse moves horizontally. If mouse moves left, it should rotate left, if mouse moves right, it should rotate right.

Unfortunately, it always rotate right.

```
package jme3test.helloworld;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication;
import com.jme3.input.MouseInput;
import com.jme3.input.controls.AnalogListener;
import com.jme3.input.controls.MouseAxisTrigger;
import com.jme3.material.Material;
import com.jme3.math.Vector3f;
import com.jme3.scene.Geometry;
import com.jme3.scene.shape.Box;
import com.jme3.math.ColorRGBA;

public class HelloJME3_3 extends SimpleApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloJME3_3.class);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        HelloJME3_3 app = new HelloJME3_3();
        app.start(); // start the game
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleInitApp() {
        Box b = new Box(1, 1, 1); // create cube shape
        final Geometry geom = new Geometry("Box", b);  // create cube geometry from the shape
        Material mat = new Material(assetManager,
          "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");  // create a simple material
        mat.setColor("Color", ColorRGBA.Blue);   // set color of material to blue
        geom.setMaterial(mat);                   // set the cube's material
        rootNode.attachChild(geom);              // make the cube appear in the scene


        flyCam.setEnabled(false); 

        inputManager.addMapping("RotateX", 
                new MouseAxisTrigger(MouseInput.AXIS_X, false),
                new MouseAxisTrigger(MouseInput.AXIS_X, true)
        );

        inputManager.addListener(new AnalogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnalog(String name, float value, float tpf) {
                log.debug(name);

                if( "RotateX".equals(name) ) {
                    //geom.rotate((float) (value*speed), 0, 0);
                    geom.rotate(0, (float) (value*speed), 0);

                }
            }
        }, "RotateX");



    }
}
```

Comment: I think your problem may be the non commutiveness of 3d rotations. A rotation about the x axis followed by a rotation about the y axis isn't the same as a rotation about the y axis followed by a rotation about the x axis. If you post a whole program I'll have a play with it

Comment: I know the rotations is not commutative. In my case rotation just appears wrong, even if about one axis.

Comment: I have a few theories I'm working on. The rest of the progam would help however

Comment: See my update. The program should rotate only around one axis. Apparently the problem concerns JME3 concepts, not geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that both positive and negative axis movements generate positive values for `value`. Hence your object only rotates one way.

The simplest solution to this is to bind positive and negative axis movements separately and manage them separately.

```
public class HelloJME_3 extends SimpleApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        HelloJME_3 app = new HelloJME_3();
        app.start(); // start the game
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleInitApp() {
        Box b = new Box(1, 1, 1); // create cube shape
        final Geometry geom = new Geometry("Box", b);  // create cube geometry from the shape
        Material mat = new Material(assetManager,
          "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");  // create a simple material
        mat.setColor("Color", ColorRGBA.Blue);   // set color of material to blue
        geom.setMaterial(mat);                   // set the cube's material
        rootNode.attachChild(geom);              // make the cube appear in the scene


        flyCam.setEnabled(false); 

        inputManager.addMapping("RotateX", 
                new MouseAxisTrigger(MouseInput.AXIS_X, true)
        );

        inputManager.addMapping("RotateX_negative", 
                new MouseAxisTrigger(MouseInput.AXIS_X, false)
        );


        inputManager.addListener(new AnalogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnalog(String name, float value, float tpf) {

                if( "RotateX".equals(name) ) {
                    geom.rotate(0, (float) (value*speed), 0);

                }else if("RotateX_negative".equals(name)){
                    geom.rotate(0, (float) (-value*speed), 0);
                }
            }
        }, "RotateX", "RotateX_negative");


    }
}
```

## Base rotation on absolute cursor position

You mentioned that you would like to create a rotation such that when the mouse is in the centre of the screen the object is unrotated. You can achieve this using the mouses screen coordinates.

```
inputManager.getCursorPosition();
```

This of course also requires you to set the rotation rather than rotating in addition to the current rotation (this takes a Quaternion argument but we largely don't have to worry about how that works.

```
  Quaternion quat=new Quaternion();
  quat.fromAngles(0, desiredAngle, 0);

  geom.setLocalRotation(quat);
```

Of course when the mouse is initially captured the object will suddenly move to its "correct" position for wherever the mouse now is.

#### Complete code

```
public class HelloJME_3 extends SimpleApplication {

    public static float PIXELSMOVED_TO_RADIANSROTATED=0.01f;


    public static void main(String[] args){
        HelloJME_3 app = new HelloJME_3();
        app.start(); // start the game
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleInitApp() {
        Box b = new Box(1, 1, 1); // create cube shape
        final Geometry geom = new Geometry("Box", b);  // create cube geometry from the shape
        Material mat = new Material(assetManager,
          "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");  // create a simple material
        mat.setColor("Color", ColorRGBA.Blue);   // set color of material to blue
        geom.setMaterial(mat);                   // set the cube's material
        rootNode.attachChild(geom);              // make the cube appear in the scene


        flyCam.setEnabled(false); 

        inputManager.addMapping("MouseMoved", 
                new MouseAxisTrigger(MouseInput.AXIS_X, false),
                new MouseAxisTrigger(MouseInput.AXIS_X, true)
        );

        inputManager.addListener(new AnalogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnalog(String name, float value, float tpf) {
                inputManager.getCursorPosition();

                    float centredX=inputManager.getCursorPosition().x-0.5f*settings.getWidth();

                    Quaternion quat=new Quaternion();
                    quat.fromAngles(0, PIXELSMOVED_TO_RADIANSROTATED*centredX, 0);

                    geom.setLocalRotation(quat);

            }
        }, "MouseMoved");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but why it "jumps" on first move?

Comment: @SuzanCioc The mouse seems to be considered to be at (0,0) before the mouse is captured (and at its last know position if focus is lost) and then makes a large jump to its true position as its captured. You'll notice there is no jump if you bring your mouse in from the left hand side. There are a couple of somewhat hackish solutions; (1) explicitly ignore the first input (doesn't help after focus is lost), (2) ignore large inputs (the normal movements are between 10^-3 and 10^4 so if its 0.01 or larger you could ignore it).

Comment: I would like to have object in "normal" position when mouse is in the center, while it is appeared so, if it is near left lower corner. Simultaneously, listener receives only incrementals, so I can't just subtract screen half sizes from it. I think it should be organized non-hackish way to do all this...

Comment: @SuzanCioc If you want the absolute mouse position you can get that with `inputManager.getCursorPosition()` and just ignore the change values you are recieving. Of course that won't solve the jumps on mouse capture; but then arguably jumping is what it should do

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar project and here is my code as it is what you are looking for.

```
    this.addControl("Positive Mouse X", new MouseAxisTrigger(MouseInput.AXIS_X, false));
    this.addControl("Negative Mouse X", new MouseAxisTrigger(MouseInput.AXIS_X, true));
    this.addControl("Positive Mouse Y", new MouseAxisTrigger(MouseInput.AXIS_Y, false));
    this.addControl("Negative Mouse Y", new MouseAxisTrigger(MouseInput.AXIS_Y, true));
```

And here is the addControl method (It is within the same class hence the use of this):

```
public void addControl(String key, Trigger trigger)
{
    inputManager.addMapping(key, trigger);
    inputManager.addListener(this, key);
}
```

It is really just meant to be a convenience method but I thought to include it if it will help.  Keep in mind that the boolean within MouseAxisTrigger is whether or not it is negative.  That means true will give you a negative value and false will give you a positive one hence my naming of the mappings.  This mix up of the booleans is a common mistake so be careful of it with future projects as I forget it often as well.

As for handling the input and doing what you want to do with the rotation of the geometry I believe that you have it right with your example code.